# Push notifications for Android from a Web App

Tags: android

A few years ago, when I had Apple devices, I stumbled across an app called Prowl (https://www.prowlapp.com/) which I used to send push notifications to my mobile from my web app.

It worked really well, and they announced they were discontinuing the app.

Today I am looking around, and notice the app is still alive, although I'm now fully Android but it seems this only works for iPhones.

So I'm after a little advice - Does anyone know of a way I can send PUSH notifications (via PHP/cURL/HTTP etc) to my Android devices?

Comment: You're probably looking for Firebase Cloud Messaging